# Java Spring App redirect wrong URL on Tomcat+Apache2

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, apache2

I have an Tomcat Server with Apache2 which reverse proxy to `dom.com:8080/myapp` from Tomcat. Which result `dom.com` to show content from `dom.com:8080/myapp`

In my app I have this page `dom.com/foo` which should redirect to `dom.com`

```
return "redirect:/";
```

But the result is `dom.com/myapp/`

How I should redirect `dom.com/foo` to `dom.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is a spring boot application, then you should define both the paths of action in your spring app. So the redirect: knows which RequestMapping to match the redirect string "/".

Otherwise, you can refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html).

Comment: Can you, please, give me a simple example? I'm not sure I understand your idea.

Comment: I thought your application was a spring boot application where we have to define every path in the application including the redirect URLs. Otherwise, am glad you found the solution. I have updated my answer with the relevant link to help any future reader with the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: I define every redirect, but the problem was the redirect was wrong. I want to redirect to `dom.com`, but instead, I end up on `dom.com/myapp/` which is wrong. Maybe my question was not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `/` could be interpreted as relative.

And also I found `RedirectView` where I can `setContextRelative(false)`(by default is false - so I don't need to set it false) which will interpret `/` as absolute.

Now I return an `View`: `new RedirectView("/")` and `dom.com/foo` will always be redirected to `dom.com`