# spring boot redirect to wrong url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

The spring boot security should redirect by default to url requested. According to
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243352/how-to-set-redirection-after-successful-login](https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-2):

> By default, Spring Security will redirect after login to the secured
> ressource you tried to access

After server is running and entering `localhost:3000/categories`, it correctly routes me to `/login` but after successful login it routes me to `http://localhost:8080/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js?continue` which of course is not `/categories`. Why is that?

*SecurityConfig.java*:

```
...
 @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
                // 1. enable project static assets
                .requestMatchers("/css/*").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/img/*").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/js/*").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/scss/*").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/vendor/*").permitAll()

                // 2. admin
                .requestMatchers("/admin/*").hasRole("ADMIN")

                // 3. enable for all
                .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/register-new").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/forgot-password").permitAll()

                // 4. else require authentication
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/do-login")
                .permitAll()
        ).logout(logout -> logout
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .permitAll()
        );
        return http.build();
    }
...
```

*LoginController.java*:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;


    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginForm() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String register(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("adminDto", new AdminDto());
        return "register";
    }

    @GetMapping("/forgot-password")
    public String forgotPassword(Model model) {
        return "forgot-password";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register-new")
    public String addNewAdmin(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("adminDto") AdminDto adminDto,
            BindingResult result,
            Model model,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        // dto is not changed anywhere so could be just passed as is
        model.addAttribute("adminDto", adminDto);
        try {
            // 1. errors in validation
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                System.out.println("there were errors");
                return "/register";
            }
            // 2. user is already registered
            if (adminService.findByUsername(adminDto.getUsername()) != null) {
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "You are already registered");
                return "redirect:/register";
            }
            // 3. password and repeatPassword do not equal
            if (!adminDto.getPassword().equals(adminDto.getRepeatPassword())) {
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Passwords are not same");
                return "redirect:/register";
            }
            // 4. success
            adminService.save(adminDto);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Registered successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // 5. all other errors
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Unknown server error");
            return "redirect:/register";
        }
        return "redirect:/register";
    }
}
```

*login.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<div th:replace="~{fragments/header::header}"></div>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

  <div class="container">

    <!-- Outer Row -->
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-xl-10 col-lg-12 col-md-9">

        <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
          <div class="card-body p-0">
            <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 d-none d-lg-block bg-login-image"></div>
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="p-5">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Welcome Back!</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                    Invalid username or password
                  </div>
                  <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-info text-center">
                    You have been logged out
                  </div>
                  <form th:action="@{/do-login}" method="post" class="user">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputEmail"
                        aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Email Address...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-user"
                        id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                      Login
                    </button>
                  </form>
                  <hr>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="small" th:href="@{/forgot-password}">Forgot Password?</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="small" th:href="@{/register}">Create an Account!</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div th:replace="~{fragments/scripts::scripts}"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

*$tree src/main/resources/templates*:

```
src/main/resources/templates/
├── categories.html
├── forgot-password.html
├── fragments
│   ├── footer.html
│   ├── header.html
│   ├── scripts.html
│   ├── sidebar.html
│   └── topbar.html
├── index.html
├── login.html
└── register.html
```

EDIT:
the frontend or the templates are from [sb-admin-2](https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-2)

EDIT2: the spring-boot security debug log:

```
2023-11-16T14:50:29.214+01:00  INFO 3766 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-11-16T14:50:29.226+01:00  INFO 3766 --- [           main] c.e.ecommerce.EcommerceApplication       : Started EcommerceApplication in 6.398 seconds (process running for 6.825)
2023-11-16T14:50:39.372+01:00  INFO 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-11-16T14:50:39.373+01:00  INFO 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-11-16T14:50:39.375+01:00  INFO 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2023-11-16T14:50:39.392+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /categories
2023-11-16T14:50:39.429+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:39.449+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/categories?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:39.450+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:39.462+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:39.463+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:39.898+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:39.962+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css
2023-11-16T14:50:39.964+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /css/sb-admin-2.min.css
2023-11-16T14:50:39.965+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js
2023-11-16T14:50:39.969+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /js/sb-admin-2.min.js
2023-11-16T14:50:39.969+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js
2023-11-16T14:50:39.971+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
2023-11-16T14:50:39.973+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /js/sb-admin-2.min.js
2023-11-16T14:50:39.975+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /css/sb-admin-2.min.css
2023-11-16T14:50:39.979+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:39.981+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:39.982+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:39.984+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:39.984+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:39.985+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:39.985+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:39.986+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:39.986+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:39.987+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:39.988+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:39.990+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:39.990+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js
2023-11-16T14:50:39.991+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /js/demo/chart-area-demo.js
2023-11-16T14:50:39.997+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js
2023-11-16T14:50:40.000+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.002+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.002+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:40.002+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.003+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.004+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/js/demo/chart-area-demo.js?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:40.004+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.006+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.008+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.009+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:40.010+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.069+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.070+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.070+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.070+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.072+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.072+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.073+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.074+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.075+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.076+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.078+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.077+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.076+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.079+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.080+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.081+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.083+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.083+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.083+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.087+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.087+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.109+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js
2023-11-16T14:50:40.113+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.114+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:40.115+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.173+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.174+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.180+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.184+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js
2023-11-16T14:50:40.188+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.189+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:40.189+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.197+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.197+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.203+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.208+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /js/demo/chart-area-demo.js
2023-11-16T14:50:40.212+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.213+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/js/demo/chart-area-demo.js?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:40.214+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.218+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.219+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.223+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.227+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js
2023-11-16T14:50:40.230+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.231+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js?continue to session
2023-11-16T14:50:40.231+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.237+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.238+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.242+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.247+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /favicon.ico
2023-11-16T14:50:40.249+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:50:40.250+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.257+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.258+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2023-11-16T14:50:40.261+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-11-16T14:52:10.158+01:00 DEBUG 3766 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /do-login
```

EDIT3:
someone may think this is answered already here [Java Spring App redirect wrong URL on Tomcat+Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56597973/java-spring-app-redirect-wrong-url-on-tomcatapache2), but there the solution is:

> Assuming it is a spring boot application, then you should define both
> the paths of action in your spring app

but I have define all paths for which I redirect, that is - for every `return "redirect:/register";` there is

```
@GetMapping("/register")
    public String register(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("adminDto", new AdminDto());
        return "register";
    }
```

so this is clearly not a solution to me.

Comment: Can you try replacing `.requestMatchers("/js/*").permitAll()` by `.requestMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()`?

Comment: @dan1st didn't worked. Instead I ended up in url `http://localhost:8080/vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js?continue`

Comment: You might need to do the same with `/vendor` and similar.

Comment: @dan1st what is the difference between `/js/*` and `/js/**`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SuccessHandler. Below is a simple example of a custom MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler class that implements both AuthenticationSuccessHandler and AuthenticationFailureHandler interfaces. This example uses Spring Security to handle authentication success and failure:

```
public class MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendRedirect("/categories");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendRedirect("/login");
    }
}
```

The onAuthenticationSuccess method handles successful authentication.
The onAuthenticationFailure method handles authentication failure.

Use it in your SecurityFilterChain:

```
http.formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .successHandler(MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(MySimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .permitAll()
        );
```